# Adguard docker cannot access web ui

Tags: docker, docker-compose

im working on a raspberry pi and trying to setup adguard home with docker compose.

First inital setup all works fine. When i start the container i can access the webUI with "HOST:3000". But when I recreate the container the webUi is no more accessible. I found out that if i delete the "AdGuardHome.yaml" within the conf folder its working again until i finish the inital setup again.

My compose file:

```
version: "3"
  adguard:
    image: adguard/adguardhome:v0.108.0-b.25
    container_name: adguard
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 53:53/tcp 
      - 53:53/udp
      - 67:67/udp 
      - 69:68/udp
      - 80:80/tcp 
      - 443:443/tcp 
      - 443:443/udp 
      - 3000:3000/tcp
      - 853:853/tcp
      - 784:784/udp 
      - 853:853/udp 
      - 8853:8853/udp
      - 5443:5443/tcp 
      - 5443:5443/udp
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    volumes:
      - /home/pi/homematicDocker/adguard/work:/opt/adguardhome/work
      - /home/pi/homematicDocker/adguard/conf:/opt/adguardhome/conf
    network_mode: host
```

The containers log:

```
2023/01/29 06:22:12.243914 [info] AdGuard Home, version v0.108.0-b.25
2023/01/29 06:22:12.244302 [info] AdGuard Home updates are disabled
2023/01/29 06:22:12.253579 [info] tls: using default ciphers
2023/01/29 06:22:12.292132 [info] Initializing auth module: /opt/adguardhome/work/data/sessions.db
2023/01/29 06:22:12.293924 [info] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:1
2023/01/29 06:22:12.294066 [info] web: initializing
2023/01/29 06:22:12.439396 [info] dnsproxy: cache: enabled, size 4096 b
2023/01/29 06:22:12.439482 [info] MaxGoroutines is set to 300
2023/01/29 06:22:12.442166 [info] AdGuard Home is available at the following addresses:
2023/01/29 06:22:12.447718 [info] Go to http://127.0.0.1:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.447818 [info] Go to http://[::1]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.447854 [info] Go to http://192.168.178.37:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.447889 [info] Go to http://[2003:f2:670b:5400:fe5f:c7b3:47e9:2db0]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.447926 [info] Go to http://[fe80::fac1:92f4:4829:1a7a%eth0]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.447961 [info] Go to http://172.17.0.1:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.447997 [info] Go to http://[fe80::42:aff:fe19:feba%docker0]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.448032 [info] Go to http://172.18.0.1:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.448235 [info] Go to http://[fe80::42:2bff:fee7:ea90%br-83f36fdc3e1b]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.448285 [info] Go to http://172.19.0.1:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.448414 [info] Go to http://[fe80::42:bfff:feef:d231%br-d48134c39c76]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.448457 [info] Go to http://[fe80::24b3:79ff:fef6:548a%veth6e52584]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.448581 [info] Go to http://[fe80::94bf:17ff:fe2c:62ed%veth6138d5a]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.448623 [info] Go to http://[fe80::4ca6:93ff:fe33:c5bb%veth4a0eccf]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.449176 [info] Go to http://[fe80::ed15:c73e:7dd0:b08e%veth919a0eb]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:12.449234 [info] Go to http://[fe80::ccb4:3c9e:5dc4:ed0%vethcedf116]:80
2023/01/29 06:22:13.626359 [info] Starting the DNS proxy server
2023/01/29 06:22:13.626421 [info] Ratelimit is enabled and set to 20 rps
2023/01/29 06:22:13.626444 [info] The server is configured to refuse ANY requests
2023/01/29 06:22:13.626526 [info] dnsproxy: cache: enabled, size 4194304 b
2023/01/29 06:22:13.626605 [info] MaxGoroutines is set to 300
2023/01/29 06:22:13.626708 [info] Creating the UDP server socket
2023/01/29 06:22:13.627076 [info] Listening to udp://[::]:53
2023/01/29 06:22:13.627115 [info] Creating a TCP server socket
2023/01/29 06:22:13.627356 [info] Listening to tcp://[::]:53
2023/01/29 06:22:13.627645 [info] Entering the UDP listener loop on [::]:53
2023/01/29 06:22:13.627645 [info] Entering the tcp listener loop on [::]:53
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the web ui by hostname without any port.
So i changed the port of the AdguardHome.yml to 3000. So its running as expected.